# Multiplying different factor based on a cell's value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to build a formula that would calculate out the following:

```
=< 10,000 x 1.00

10,0001-12,500 x 1.25

12,501 - 15,000 x 1.50
```

Examples:

If the number is 8,520
(8,520 x 1.00) = 8,520

If the number was 11,560
(10,000 x 1.00) + (1,560 x 1.25) = 11,950

If the number is 13,500
(10,000 x 1.00) + (2,500 x 1.25) + (1,000 x 1.50) = 14,625

Comment: Yeah, what have you tried? Sounds like nested `IF` would work.

Comment: I would put your lower limits in a table with the multiplier then a simple vlookup to return the multiplier and multiply it by the number.

Comment: What happens to values over 15,000?

Comment: See my edit below I mixed my approach with the formula of @fixer1234

Answer (score 2):

Okay it was bit more complicated than first thought.

create a table like the following:

[image]

Then use the following array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(A2>$D$2:$D$4,IF(A2<$E$2:$E$4,A2-$D$2:$D$4,$E$2:$E$4-$D$2:$D$4)*$F$2:$F$4,0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

Building on @fixer's formula and making the formula dynamic we create a table like this:

[image]

As you can see the Factor is now the increase from the previous and not the actual factor.

Then we can use this formula:

```
=A2+SUMPRODUCT((A2>$D$3:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1E+99,D:D)))*MOD(A2,$D$3:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1E+99,D:D)))*$E$3:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,D:D)))
```

The Formula is now dynamic in that as the table grows or shrinks so will the reference to the dataset.  The `INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1E+99,D:D))` finds the last cell in the column and sets that as the extent of the dataset.

[image]

Comment: You were right on the MOD function.  I just deleted the answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 I just incorporated it into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a if. The way to build a nested if is to do what happens on different values. Assuming column of data starting in A2, then

1. A2<10000. Result is a2 + 0  or A2
2. 10000 < A2 <12501 Result is a2 +(.25 * (A2-10000) )
3. 12500 < A2 <15000 Result is  a2 +(.25* (a2-10000)) + (.25 *( A2-12500))

To convert this to a single formula just use a if for each case. The flow is =if(test,true,false) where if test is true, get true value, else get false value. The first solution uses 3 ifs, false test result in a zero, true results in the answer

- =IF(A2<10001,A2,0)+IF(AND(A2>10000,A2<12501),A2+(0.25*(A2-10000))+IF(AND(A2>12500,A2<15001),A2+(0.25*(A2-10000))+(0.25*(A2-12500))))

This can be simplified by using some algebra to

- =A2+IF(A2>10000,(0.25*(A2-10000)),0)+IF(A2>12500,(0.25*(A2-12500)))

Either form can be changed on how want to deal with numbers greater than 15,000

Comment: You were right.  I deleted the answer.